# How to make plotly graph function less laggier and more distinct in R for many datapoints?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Currently, I have a lot of datapoints, and its not really distinguishable by color. How can I make the colors more distinguishiable, or do I have to make a graph other than scatterplot that may better display my data? Also, My plotly graph is super laggy and has 40 warning messages. How do I make a plotly graph that is less laggier and more distinguishable by color. My ggplot doesn't have this lagginess problem but I don't want to use ggplot because I want it to be interactive.

```
#ggplot function for graph
scatter_n <- function(new_data) {
  b <- ggplot(data = new_data, aes(x = current_votes, y = percent, color = candidate)) +
    geom_point() 
  return(b)
}

scatter_n(df3)

([![ggplot][1]][1]



# Plotly function for graph

scatter_b <- function(new_data) {
  c <- plot_ly(data = new_data, x = ~current_votes, y = ~percent, color = ~candidate, Type = "scatter", Mode = "markers") %>%
    layout(
      title = "Percentage of Votes for each candidate by population",
      xaxis = list(title = "Current Votes"),
      yaxis = list(title = "Percentage", ticksuffix = "%")
    )
  return(c)
}
```

[image: plotly graph]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about what you want to represent. Both your axes represent almost the same data (votes), so a scatter plot might not be the most appropriate way of visualizing it. What about using `geom_col()` to plot the candidates in the x axis and the number of votes in the y axis?
If you want to add the percentages, you can add it as text with `geom_text()` on top of the bars.

You can also turn the ggplot graph into plotly with `ggplotly()`, to keep it interactive